# PyQt - Window().show() fails but var = Window(); var.show() works?

Tags: python, constructor, pyqt, variable-assignment

Here is some sample code I was messing around with, when I discovered something I simply don't understand.

This code seems to work

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

ap = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
var = Window()
var.show()
sys.exit(ap.exec_())
```

But this causes the window to appear than disappear in quick succession. (Second bottom line altered)

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

ap = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
Window().show()
sys.exit(ap.exec_())
```

I simply can not understand why. In all my understanding of python and Qt, I can't fathom why the bottom fails. Is it being garbage collected or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Both of those examples should yell about indentation errors since nothing is in the `__init__` bodies.

Comment: Corrected. My test code had a bunch of other rubbish commented out, with pass suffixed. I deleted it all when making the question for clarity, and forgot to add back in the pass statements

Answer (score 3):

In the second version you don't keep a reference to the `Window` instance, so Python will destroy it after executing that line of code. In the first version you keep a reference in `var` throught the block of code. Most importantly, `var` exists while you call `ap.exec_()`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's actually happening? What do you mean by 'free'. Why do I see it at all then?

Comment: See edited answer. You see it when you call `show()`, it is destroyed after.

Answer (score 0):

It works but instead of writing `pass` in `__init__()`, put this:

```
super(Window, self).__init__()
```

Your `__init__()` function is empty.

Here is the full code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

ap = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
var = Window()
var.show()
sys.exit(ap.exec_())
```

I tested this with PySide, should work on PyQt too.

Comment: I absented the superclass constructor because it didn't affect the results. Your 'full code' works because it has a dedicated variable `var`, not because of the constructors.